# How to be explicit about NOT throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

This might be a broad question, but recently I ahve wondered about the following: In our C# backend we have many places that wrap some code in a `try`/`catch` block, specifically calls to external WcF services. Some of these calls are crucial for the application so in the catch block we log the error and rethrow, like:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error("Some good error message");
    throw ex;
}
```

On the other hand there are services we allow to fail, but we still want to log the error, so they look like:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error("Some good error message");
}
```

Now reading the code of team members I can not be sure if they *forgot* to throw or if this is the intended behaviour.

**Q:** Is there a way, resp. what is the default way, to explicitly NOT rethrow (without including a comment in the code).

I have considered something like this:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error("Some good error message");
    NotThrowingHereOnPurpose();
}

// ...
// and further below a private method
// ...

private void NotThrowingHereOnPurpose(){}
```

Comment: "without including a comment in the code" - Why not?

Comment: Closest thing I can think of is the explicit distinction in some parsing methods, e.g. `int.Parse` vs. `int.TryParse`. Maybe that would work for you. In the end the naming-convention is up to you I guess?

Comment: The 2nd way is literally the way to do this. A comment is the way to "explain" anything in code. Anything else is a human problem.

Comment: Rethrow with `throw;` not `throw ex` which creates a new stack trace, i guess you want to keep the informations where the exception really occured.

Comment: What's better in calling a fake method `NotThrowingHereOnPurpose` opposed to adding readable documentation? There is no _default_ way, if it's intended that you want to swallow the exception(only log it), then that's the way the method is implemented. Add a comment if necessary. On the other hand, rethrowing every exception is _not_ the default way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ofc, that was a mistake when typing up the example...

Comment: @EluciusFTW I still don't understand why you wouldn't want devs to document this by comment? Personally, I would still want a comment on _why_ this Exception is purposely swallowed even if it was perfectly clear _that_ it was on purpose.

Comment: @Fildor My question was if there is a standard way without having a comment in code. It was not whether or not to include a comment here. Ofc a comment is a possibility...

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I misunderstood your wording - my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found another way that kind of includes what other have suggested here, but uses a built in feature: **exception filters**. I was free to modify the example given in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#string-interpolation) to illustrate this:

```
public void MethodThatFailsSometimes()
{
    try {
        PerformFailingOperation();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) when (e.LogAndBeCaught())
    {
    }
}
```

and then one could have two extension methods on `Exception`, say `LogAndBeCaught` and `LogAndEscape` like so:

```
public static bool LogAndBeCaught(this Exception e)
{
    _logger.Error(@"Following exception was thrown: {e}");
    return true;
} 

public static bool LogAndEscape(this Exception e)
{
    _logger.Error(@"Following exception was thrown: {e}");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach that may be useful here is to change the way of invoking the code that you explicitly allow to fail in such a way that it does not look like a `try`/`catch` block at all.

For example, you could write a helper method that does error reporting, and call it with actions expressed as lambdas:

```
void InvokeFailSafe(Action action, Action<Exception> onFailure = null) {
    try {
        action();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (onFailure != null) {
            onFailure(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead of `try`/`catch` you would write this:

```
InvokeFailSafe(
    () => {
        ... The code that may fail
    }
,   exception => _logger.Error("Some good error message: {0}", exception)
);
```

or like this, if you don't want anything logged:

```
InvokeFailSafe(
    () => {
        ... The code that may fail
    }
);
```

If you code things this way, there would be no doubts about a missing `throw` statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed I have also thought about creating a method runner like this ...

Comment: Consider changing onFailure to have a default of `null`, and then do a null check before invoking it. That way callers can pass nothing to indicate 'I don't care about exceptions here'.

Comment: @mjwills Why in the world would you want to make it easy to just swallow exceptions?  It's something that either shouldn't be done, or should be *very* rare and that you want people to go out of their way to explicitly do to indicate that they really meant to do it.

Comment: @Servy That is certainly a defensible argument. A possible counter-argument is that it is **already** easy to just swallow exceptions (i.e. just do an empty catch block). If you are really concerned, you could split the problem into two parts - one being `InvokeFailSafe` and the other being `InvokeFailSafeAndSwallowExceptions` - to make it more explicit.

Comment: @Servy Calling a method designated to swallow exceptions is about as explicit an indication of an intention as it gets, isn't it?

Comment: @mjwills An empty `catch` block is something that should stand out to any competent programmer as a giant red flag as something that's almost certainly wrong and that need immediate attention.  Seeing a call to `InvokeFailSafe` with only one argument instead of two is not going to stand out to all programmers in the same way.  Additionally the name implies it's able to fail safely even though it in no way actually ensures that the method fails safely, meaning that the name of the method is lying to me.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Nothing about this method tells me it's goal is to swallow exceptions and that it shouldn't be called under almost any circumstances.  `InvokeFailSafe` tells me that the method is going to ensure that it fails safely, which it doesn't actually do, it just ensure that if the method fails that nobody knows about it (which is about the least safe way one can possibly fail).  If the method was named, `ThisIsADangerousMethodDontCallIt` then sure, it stands out and I know to be highly suspicious of any calls to it that I see when looking through code.

Answer (score 1):

It's an opposite solution to dasblinkenlight's answer. Instead of notifying others that the exception mustn't be rethrown it would say that it must be.

If you only want to log it then use the `Error` method as usual. Otherwise, you can write an extension method for your logger to log and throw exceptions.

The method would take the catched exception and rethrow it using the [`ExceptionDispatchInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo) class. The `ExceptionDispatchInfo` is used to rethrow the exception with the original stack trace information and Watson information. It behaves like `throw;` (without the specified exception).

```
public static void ErrorAndThrow(this ILogger logger, string message, Exception exception)
{
    var exceptionInfo = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception);

    logger.Error(message);
    exceptionInfo.Throw();
}
```

And use it this way:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // ex would be rethrown here
    _logger.ErrorAndThrow("Some good error message", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: Is there a way, resp. what is the default way, to explicitly NOT
>   rethrow (without including a comment in the code).

Ideal way would be not to catch a generic exception. Now, to throw or not that entirely depends on your case. You need to understand that Exception handling is used when you know what to do in case an exception occurs. So, only specific exceptions should be handled. Catching exceptions without knowing what you are catching will change the behavior of your application.

> Now reading the code of team members I can not be sure if they forgot
>   to throw or if this is the intended behaviour.

This is something the author of the code can explain to you. But here is a learning to take from this. Your code should be self explanatory. In specific cases where you are unable to express yourself with the code, add a meaningful comment.

You can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/) for better understanding.

Comment: I tried to abstract too much away from the problem in my code above in an attempt to make the question clear, but I seem to have failed ... Actually I do catch only specific exceptions, for which I wanted this question to apply, not a generic one.